# best way to determine proximity to location with a list of latlng with Google Map API

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I'm under a 2-day crunch deadline (my own undoing, I know), and I need to implement a function in Wordpress that searches through a bunch of posts with custom content containing locations in a known field in wp_postmeta, (NOT geocoded) and shows a list of them based on proximity (i.e., within 20 miles) to a specific geocode.

I have no problem with the WP query - I'm just a little new to Google Map API, and the docs aren't terribly straightforward with regards to geocoding, which I ASSUME I have to do to determine proximity.

Additionally, I assume I'll just have to iterate through the list of each post and determine one at a time if they meet the proximity requirement.

I'm not asking for someone to do this for me, unless you w3ant to be paid to do it for me - I just need to be pointed in the right direction quickly.  I can;t find ANYONE who knows how to do this - and I have some budget for it...

Comment: Am I down-voted because I'm looking for direction? Because I made a stupid error and booked a gig I was unprepared-for? I'd love some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I was researching for something similar a few days ago. How to handle a 4M geolocation record database with a fast SQL query.

**And [this page](http://vinsol.com/blog/2011/08/30/geoproximity-search-with-mysql/) + [this pdf](http://www.arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf) helped.**

Depends on what you store in your DB but iterating through each post every time will be slow. You need to offload the geolocation query to SQL level.

**PS**: *I know link only responses are frowned upon...*

Answer (score 1):

Here are two starter scripts which you will need to modify

PHP

```
function buildGeocode($address_1, $address_2, $city, $state, $zip_code, $country){

        $base_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";

        $address = $address_1 . ' ' . $address_2 . ', ' . $city . ' ' . $state . ' ' . $zip_code . ' ' . $country;

        $request_url = $base_url . "?address=" . urlencode($address) . "&sensor=false";

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($request_url), true);

        return array('lat' => $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'], 'lng' => $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']);

}
```

MySQL

```
"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
            *
            FROM (SELECT location_tbl.*, ( 3959*(2*ASIN(SQRT(POW(SIN(((location_tbl.lat-" . $lat . ")*(PI()/180))/2),2)+COS(location_tbl.lat*0.017453293)*COS(" . $lat . "*0.017453293)*POW(SIN(((location_tbl.lng-" . $lng . ")*(PI()/180))/2),2)))) ) AS distance
                FROM location_tbl
            WHERE location_tbl.active = 1 AND location_tbl.deleted = 0) AS tmp_tbl
        WHERE distance <= '" . $dis . "'
        ORDER BY distance ASC"
```